# How to save weights of keras model for each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to save keras model and I want to save weights of each epoch to have best weights. How I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

**code**:

```
def createModel():
    input_shape=(1, 22, 5, 3844)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv3D(16, (22, 5, 5), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #C2
    model.add(Conv3D(32, (1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

     #C3
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (1,3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",padding='same' ))
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use model.get_weights() and LambdaCallback function together:

1. *model.get_weights()*: Returns a list of all weight tensors in the model, as Numpy arrays.

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   weights = model.get_weights()
   ```
2. *LambdaCallback*: This callback is constructed with anonymous functions that will be called at the appropriate time

   ```
   import json
   json_log = open('loss_log.json', mode='wt', buffering=1)
   json_logging_callback = LambdaCallback(
               on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: json_log.write(
                   json.dumps({'epoch': epoch, 'loss': logs['loss']}) + '\n'),
               on_train_end=lambda logs: json_log.close()
   )

   model.fit(...,
             callbacks=[json_logging_callback])
   ```

When your code is considered, you should write *callback* function and add to your *model*:

```
import json
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

json_log = open('loss_log.json', mode='wt', buffering=1)
json_logging_callback = LambdaCallback(
            on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: json_log.write(
                json.dumps({'epoch': epoch, 
                            'loss': logs['loss'],
                            'weights': model.get_weights()}) + '\n'),
            on_train_end=lambda logs: json_log.close()
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt_adam, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(..., callbacks=[json_logging_callback])
```

This code write your all weights in all layers to json file. If you want to save weights in specific layer, just change the code with

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

Answer (score 3):

`model.get_weights()` will return a tensor as a numpy array. You can save those weights in a file with extension `.npy` using `np.save()`.

To save weights every epoch, you can use something known as callbacks in Keras.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

Before you do `model.fit()`, define a checkpoint as below:

`checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(.....)`, assign the argument 'period' as 1 which assigns the periodicity of epochs. This should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a ModelCheckpoint callback using `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`  to save weights every epoch. If you are using recent Tensorflow like `TF2.1` or later, then You need to use `save_freq='epoch'` to save weights every epoch instead of using `period=1` as other answer mentioned. Please check entire [example here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Keras_model_checkpoint.ipynb)

#### callback is as follows

```
checkpoint_path = "./training_2/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
   checkpoint_path, verbose=1, save_weights_only=True,
   # Save weights, every epoch.
   save_freq='epoch')
```

#### calling the model training

```
# Create a basic model instance
model=create_model()
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path.format(epoch=0))
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
         epochs = 50, callbacks = [cp_callback],
         validation_data = (x_test,y_test),
         verbose=0)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Janapali thanks a lot for the solution.I get this error when I run the code `AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_ckpt_saved_epoch'`.

Comment: @gigi where did you find that error? was that from my shared example? If not from my example, can you please share the code? My example code is also for Sequential only and worked for me without any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will work but you can try writing callback and inside callback you can save the weights.

Eg.

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("best_model.hdf5", monitor='loss', verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

source = https://medium.com/@italojs/saving-your-weights-for-each-epoch-keras-callbacks-b494d9648202