# parameters of deep learning for STFT and DWT input data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I create CNN model on STFT data and Discrete wavelet transform data. I want to get the number of the weights and biases of my deep learning model on the 2 input data in python . How to do that ??

Any help would be appreciated.

**code:**

```
def createModel():
   with tf.device("cpu"):
        input_shape=(1, 22, 5, 3844)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv3D(16, (22, 5, 5), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))

        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",  padding='same'))

        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv3D(32, (1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding

        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", ))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv3D(64, (1,3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",padding='same' ))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
        opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation. I can not understand the question properly. Which parameters do you want to get?

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari I mean the weights of the connection which are learned during the training stage.

Comment: So you want to get weights of every layer of your CNN network during training?  Do I understand right?

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari I use this 2 lines and i get the weights of each epoch but i don't know how to open the file ?? `filepath_1="weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
            call=keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath_1, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)`
and How to know the number of weights and biases of my model ??

Comment: Ok so you have hd5 file and can not open. Also you are looking a way to understand the format of this file. Am I right?

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari yes exactly.

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari yes exactly.

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is installing h5py

```
pip install h5py
```

And then you can explore keras model inside this file

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('mytestfile.hdf5', 'r')
# layer names of your model
list(f.keys())
# you can use this layers as index
d = f['dense']['dense_1']['kernel:0']
```

Comment: I don't understand where I add those lines and why
`# layer names of your model
list(f.keys())
# you can use this layers as index
d = f['dense']['dense_1']['kernel:0']`

Comment: After run your model and hd5 file installed in your local directory, run this code to inspect this file.

Comment: after running my model i write in the console `import h5py 
f = h5py.File('mytestfile.hdf5', 'r') 
list(f.keys())` this output appear `['batch_normalization_1',
 'batch_normalization_2',
 'batch_normalization_3',
 'conv3d_1',
 'conv3d_2',
 'conv3d_3',
 'dense_1',
 'dense_2',
 'dropout_1',
 'dropout_2',
 'flatten_1',
 'max_pooling3d_1',
 'max_pooling3d_2',
 'max_pooling3d_3']`
what the next step i should do ?? and how the file will be opened ??

Comment: These are the keys of this dictionary which holds the parameters your model. To explore such parameters, you can use print(f['dense']['dense1']) or print(f['dense_1']). You have to look inside this hierarchical dictionary. There is no easy way to read such files. Another option can be https://pypi.org/project/ViTables/ which helps you to visualize hierarchical tables

Comment: My target is to know the number of weights and bias in my model not to open the hdf5 . Is there another way to know just the number of weights and bias ??

Comment: I will also try to open the file using your last comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046870/how-to-save-weights-of-keras-model-for-each-epoch/61047335#61047335 you can save weights with callback fucntion as mentioned here. Are you looking for biases??

Comment: yes I want to know just the number of weights and biases of my model when using 2 different input data .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212373/discussion-between-abdullah-deliogullari-and-gigi).